# if $G$ is a connected planar graph with $|V| = v$ and $|E| =e$ and each cycle in the graph is of at least length $k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> if $G$ is a connected planar graph with $|V| = v$ and $|E| =e$ and
>   each cycle in the graph is of at least length $k$, Prove that $e \leq
>  { \big( \frac{k}{k-2} \big)} {(v -2)}$.

I was thinking to use euler's formula $e = f + v -2$ to prove this, But first I have to argue that $kf \leq 2e$ and then from here I will out this into euler's formula to get $$ke  = kv + kf - 2k \implies ke  = kv + kf - 2k \leq kv + 2e -2k  $$

So now we have $$ ke \leq kv + 2e -2k \implies ke -2e \leq k(v -2) \implies e(k-2) \leq k(v-2) \implies e \leq \big( \frac{k}{k-2} \big) (v -2)$$.

But How would I argue in the first place that $kf \leq 2e$ to be able to proceed with my argument ?

Comment: Put a pebble on each side of each edge, and find two different ways to count the number of pebbles.

Comment: Well I can count it by using the number of vertices, For example, two vertices connected by an edge will have two pebbles, three vertices in connected in a triangle (cycle) manner will have  three pebbles, now four vertices connected as a square will have $4$ pebbles and so on, and so in general the number of pebbles will be equal to the number of vertices. or we can count them using the number of vertices, one edge = 2 pebbles, two edges  = 3, 3three edges = 3 and so @GerryMyerson

Comment: No, the number of pebbles will not be the number of vertices. Draw an example, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the proof of Theorem 6.10 in:

http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%206.PDF

As you guess at first we must prove: $kf\leq 2e$

Note: girth is the length of the smallest cycle